# Reset setTimeout after a period of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, cleartimeout

Struggling to workout where 'clearTimeout' would fit in to this flow:

```
$(window).ready(function() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.hoverone').addClass('flip');
  }, 2000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.hovertwo').addClass('flip');
  }, 2500);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.hoverone').removeClass('flip');
  }, 4000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.hovertwo').removeClass('flip');
  }, 4500);

});
```

Once the last action has been made - I would like the timer to reset and the flow to begin again. I tried clearTimeout but I have a very specific flow of timed actions I need to complete.

Comment: [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout)

Comment: There is no repeated timer to "reset" in your example (they would have been `setInterval`). What is the aim of the excercise?

Comment: have you tried calling function like loop!!!

Comment: @RayonDabre is right. Read how to use `setTimeout/clearTimeout`s. tl;dr - Store the `setTimeout()` in a variable, then use `clearTimeout(myVariable)`.

Comment: Hi evolutionxbox - I can work this for a click function but can't seem to get the timed element configured to have it reset automatically

Comment: do you want to add and remove these classes again and again for some effect?

Comment: @nisar, that is not gonna work.

Comment: Yes Mike - but when completed it'll all have a certain timed order - once it's over (after perhaps 30 secs) - that order can start again

Comment: ok. You can keep this code ( these 4 setTimeout's ) in a function. Then once you know how long you need to set the interval for, you can call it like `setInterval( functionName, 8000 );`, where 8000 means you want the cycle to repeat after 8 seconds.

Comment: Perfect - thanks Mike..! Posting the answer now...

Comment: @trincot why it is not gonna work?  I post code here..Tell me what is wrong with this..I ll correct anyway.

Comment: @nisar, looking at your solution I see you are not using a loop. Probably we have a different interpretation of what *like loop* means. I thought you were hinting at the use of a loop construct like `for` or `while`. So, all OK!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use wrap all your set timeouts in a function. This way you dont need to clear the timeout.

```
var intervalFunction = function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
     $('.hoverone').addClass('flip');
  }, 2000);

  setTimeout(function() {
     $('.hovertwo').addClass('flip');
  }, 2500);

  setTimeout(function() {
     $('.hoverone').removeClass('flip');
  }, 4000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.hovertwo').removeClass('flip');
    intervalFunction();
  }, 4500);
}

$(window).ready(intervalFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Answer for anyone else looking - thanks to [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3801947/mike)

```
$(window).ready(function flow(){        


  setTimeout(function() {   
    $('.hoverone').addClass('flip'); 
},
  2000);

  setTimeout(function() {   
    $('.hovertwo').addClass('flip'); 
},
  2500);

   setTimeout(function() {   
    $('.hoverone').removeClass('flip'); 
},
  4000);

     setTimeout(function() {   
    $('.hovertwo').removeClass('flip'); 
},
  4500);

 setInterval( flow, 8000 );


});
```

Comment: This is not correct, as it will keep creating interval timers (every 8 seconds an additional one is created while the previous ones still keep running). The visual effect will still be OK, but sooner or later the browser will run out of resources.

Comment: Very true after testing - I think the other solutions posted definitely work better. Thank you

Comment: which approach are you using now? Because I don't think, we need to clearTimeout for the timeouts as they are gone once executed. And setInterval is set to run repeatedly. So just wanted to know, which method worked best for you.

Comment: zedling 's method is working really well - setting the times in one place is also extremely useful for my purpose

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
$(window).ready(function() {

  //all setTimeouts start (almost) the same time
  var time1 = 2000,
      time2 = time1 + 500,
      time3 = time2 + 1500,
      time4 = time3 + 500,
      repeatTime = time4 + 1000; //delay before the restart

  //this will run again and again until you stop it
  //basically it will start over after 1 second after the 4th settimeout is finished
  var Fn = setInterval(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.hoverone').addClass('flip');
    }, time1);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.hovertwo').addClass('flip');
    }, time2);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.hoverone').removeClass('flip');
    }, time3);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.hovertwo').removeClass('flip');
    }, time4);
  }, repeatTime);

  //this is how you stop it from repeating anymore
  //clearInterval(Fn);
});
```

I think this is self-explanatory, but feel free to question further.

Answer (score 0):

To repeat these time events, you should use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval). Also, you can combine the four actions in one function:

```
$(window).ready(function(){       
    var halfSeconds = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {   
        halfSeconds = (halfSeconds + 1) % 12; // change the 12 to adjust repeat-delay
        if (halfSeconds === 4) $('.hoverone').addClass('flip'); 
        if (halfSeconds === 5) $('.hovertwo').addClass('flip'); 
        if (halfSeconds === 8) $('.hoverone').removeClass('flip'); 
        if (halfSeconds === 9) $('.hovertwo').removeClass('flip');
    },
    500);

    // Optional: if you have an event that should stop the repetition:
    $('#myStopButton').click(function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
    });
});
```

It will also be useful to keep the return value from `setInterval` so you can stop the animation when some event occurs (like a click on a "stop" button).

Comment: @JackAllen, could you let me know if this answer solved your issue? Could you give some feed-back?

Answer (score 0):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nisr19/op7w3j6f/1/)

```
$(window).ready(function(){     
var hoverone,hovertwo;
call();
function call(){
       hoverone= setTimeout(function() {   
          $('.hoverone').addClass('flip'); 
          clearTimeout(hovertwo);
          call1();
      },
        2000);
  }

  function call1(){
          hovertwo =  setTimeout(function() {   
          $('.hovertwo').addClass('flip');
          clearTimeout(hoverone);
          call2();
      }, 2500);
  }
  function call2(){
          hovertwo =  setTimeout(function() {   
          $('.hoverone').removeClass('flip');
          clearTimeout(hoverone);
          call3();
      }, 2500);
  }
  function call3(){
          hovertwo =  setTimeout(function() {   
          $('.hovertwo').removeClass('flip');
          clearTimeout(hoverone);
          call();
      }, 2500);
  }
});
```